# Can we put back button at the bottom in iOS app? Are there any apps in App Store like that?

Tags: interface-design, designers, ios, button

There is a usability issue of reaching back button in iOS because it is on the top left. I want to put it at the bottom left for reachability. But my developer says it is against Apple guidelines. Can we put back button at the bottom in iOS app? Are there any apps in App Store like that?

Here is an example:[image]

Comment: Are there exceptions to Apple's Guidelines in this way? Maybe. Is it a good idea to go against Apple's guidelines for something so common? Probably not. But like everything, there are sometimes circumstances where something like this would make sense. There's nothing much we can help you with though.

Comment: Seems to me reviewing the Apple guidelines would answer your questions as to "if" and "how".  There's clearly a standard set by looking at apps on my iPhone -- many of which have a "back" button *consistently* in the top left corner.

Answer (score 2):

Several things to unpack here:

> There is a usability issue of reaching back button in iOS because it is on the top left.

This is not a usability issue - if it were, then the vast preponderance of iOS designs which conform to the Apple dev guidlines would be driving huge failure rates, mis-use stats etc to demonstrate this "usability issue" - this is not the case.

> I want to put it at the bottom left for reachability.

Apple iOS dev guidelines suggest an icon tray in the bottom location, which can allow hopping from one activity bin to another in the app, accomplishing far more legible navigation than a non-contextualising element like a browser-style "back" button - see almost ***any*** *well developed* iOS app, from Apple's own App Store app to Art-Station's curated design app to Behance's app to the New York Times app - ***all*** use the *bottom touchable nav icon bar* - and when / where there is a back button, it's ***always*** upper left as mandated by Apple. Part of the reason they mandate stuff like this is for consistency - which, by the way, aides ease-of-use by closely tying user expectations to achieved results.

> But my developer says it is against Apple guidelines. Can we put back button at the bottom in iOS app? Are there any apps in App Store like that?

Whether or not **others** have violated this guideline and somehow snuck through the QA process seems *irrelevant* compared drilling down to state to the simplest version of your question:

*"Should we willfully and capriciously violate the Apple iOS Developer Guidelines in an app we are developing to deploy on iOS through Apple's QA and App Store process?"*

To which my answer is: **"Nope - I think not"**.

Quick review: Apple's iOS dev guidelines are clear, allow wiggle room on many things, but ***not*** on the **basics** of the OS interface paradigm, which ***is*** in fact *theirs to mandate.*

The simple effect of highly-design-focussed consistency is an aura of quality - of reliability and a marriage of beauty and function.

It's where iOS stands head and shoulders apart from the Wild West of Android's interface cludges, and the same of Mac OS apps vs their typical Windows equivalents - in Mac OS, Preferences is ALWAYS in the same location, whereas in Windows, the location and naming of "Options" or "Settings" or "Preferences" is up to the developer, and is therefore totally unpredictable for the typical user, and in many cases changes in the same software package from version to version - precisely because it's **not** mandated by Microsoft to be simple and consistent.

**TL;DR**: Your whim or personal preference is not the same thing as “a usability issue” - actual usability issues are quantifiable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The fact that something is entrenched in the OS guidelines does not automatically mean it’s not bad UX, nor that apps that don’t conform to it would be “driving huge failure rates”, etc. Browsers on iOS, including Apple’s own Safari, have the back button at the bottom left, and it is indeed much easier to use the back button there than in apps that have it top left, especially if they don’t support gestures (like Flickr). There is certainly no usability issue with it. Also the fact that Android’s built-in back button is bottom left is not random.

Answer (score 0):

## Use gestures instead.

As stated in Gerard’s answer, you should stay consistent with the default navigation bar.

iOS already provides gesture-based alternatives to back/close/cancel buttons. They can be done from the bottom part of the screen. Users will expect your app to support these gestures.

- **In a [modal view](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/modality/)** (like in your example), users can swipe down to dismiss the sheet.

[image]

- **In a [hierarchical navigation](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/navigation/)**, users can swipe from the left edge to go back.

[image]

- And everywhere, users can use the [*Reachability*](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/touch-iph77bcdd132/14.0/ios/14.0#iph145eba8e9) feature to access more easily the items at the top of the screen (but it’s not enabled by default).

[image]